# Не могу вывести в списке , третью по величине стоймость товара(ов)

Tags: mysql

Есть список товаров, у каждого из них есть своя стоимость, мне надо вывести третьи по величине стоимости товары.

Например, у нас есть 7 разных товаров с определенными стоимостями:

```
Груша 10
Яблоко 20
Помидо 20
Хлеб 5
Мясо 50
Молоко 4
Сыр 25
```

Нужно написать код, который выдаст, что на третьем месте по стоимости товаров будут яблоко и помидор (20 — третья по величине стоимость, после 25 и 50)

А если, например, «молоко» тоже стоит 20, то нужно вывести, что на третьем месте по стоимости товаров будет яблоко, помидор и молоко. При этом код не должен измениться.

В моем коде, каждый раз надо самому указывать до какого места выводить список товаров.

Вот мой пример:

```
SELECT s.name, s.salary
FROM score AS s
ORDER BY s.salary DESC
LIMIT 2,1;
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос как-то не очень понятен, переформулируйте его

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос данные с таблицы + ожидаемый результат. Не могу понять, что вы хотите

Comment: Если бы стоимости были 50 50 25 25 20 20, то на третьем месте было бы 20 или 25?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct salary into @salary3 from score order by salary desc limit 2,1;
select s.name, s.salary from score s where salary = @salary3;
```

Код полностью: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34b4ed/5